# How can I hide Disqus from websites that I visit?

Tags: blog, google-chrome, comments, disqus

Often when I visit a webpage, the comments section is many times longer than the actual post. This makes scrolling very cumbersome, as the actual post takes up a very small portion of the scrollbar.

I almost never actually want to read the comments, and there doesn't appear to be a way to "roll-up" the comments section. I can open up the developer console and delete the relevant `div`, but this is a lot of effort to do repeatedly.

How can I hide Disqus on *all* websites that I visit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [WidgetBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgiihiookhijpbhaflohognbhmamdnol) Chrome extension, and disabling it for all domains except disqus.com.

Answer (score 3):

By installing an extension/add-on that does it, like [Ghostery](http://www.ghostery.com/). It blocks/removes a lot of things, but you can just select Disqus out of the preferences list and that’s it.

---

Note that blocking some “bugs,” as they are called by Ghostery, means blocking JavaScript scripts, which might lead to some related errors on different pages, depending on various factors. However, it’s not that big of a deal, and you can overcome this by allowing exceptions for different pages.

Answer (score 3):

The actual solution is to add the following line to your uBlockOrigin/AdBlock filter:

```
###disqus_thread
```